# Wordpress giving a 404 page when passing a year argument different than the current year

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

On this page you will see I'm listing events that fall in certain months: http://conciergemaps.ch/events/

This is on Wordpress, When you select a certain month and year it appends the URL with two arguments (month and year i.e. ?month=October&year=2014). The problem is if the year is anything other than the current year (2014), it gives a 404 error. I use the below code to only show the correct events that fall under the selected month (they're a custom post type):

```
$events_month = sanitize_text_field($_GET["month"]);
$events_year = sanitize_text_field($_GET["year"]);

if (empty($events_month) || empty($events_year)) {

    $events_month = date('F');
    $events_year = date('Y');

}

$ts = strtotime("$events_month $events_year");

$month_start_date = date('Ym01', $ts);
$month_end_date = date('Ymt', $ts);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $month_end_date,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'finish_date',
            'value' => $month_start_date,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
);

$events = new WP_Query($args);
```

Why is this causing a 404 when the year is anything other than the current year?

Comment: Do you have any events in 2015? When I look at the main events page, I'm just seeing 2014 events. Is it possible there are no 2015 events created, so the query isn't finding any posts?

Comment: I add a test event for january 2015 and it still didn't display. The page should just show "there are no events to display" if there are none for the current month, but the problem is wordpress isn't using this page if the year argument is not 2014, it just throws up the 404 page which is the wrong template

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was with using 'year' as the argument name, if I changed it to something else such as 'y' it seems to work.